# Using link abbrevations for EXPORT_FILE_NAME?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

on orgmode 8.3.2 I've got a large org-file. Offen, I need to export a subtree like this:

---

```
* Subtree to be exported
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: /PATH/TO/FOLDER/filename
:EXPORT_TITLE:
:END:

foo
```

---

I'd like to save the exported file in a project folder, as you can see in 
EXPORT_FILE_NAME . This is a different folder than folder where my large org file resides.

It would be very helpful to use link abbrevations in EXPORT_FILE_NAME :

```
(setq org-link-abbrev-alist
   '(("anglisky" . "~/Path/whereever/%s")))
```

in .emacs and write:

---

```
* Subtree to be exported
:PROPERTIES:
:EXPORT_FILE_NAME: anglisky:filename
:EXPORT_TITLE:
:END:

foo
```

---

Possible? Feature Request?

The trick in my `org-link-abbrev-alist` is that the path depends, e.g. on the OS of the computer. Under Windows, the path  may be X:/..., under Linux the path is /home/<user>/whatever/else/

So it would be very helpful to use link abbrevation for the export file name.

I've been asking this question on the orgmode-mailing-list, but without an answer.

---

**EDIT**

There has been an answer on the orgmode mailinglist: no, it is not possible to use the link abbrevations for the properties list. Sorry, I can't provide a link, Gmane seems to be down.

What a pity, but I'll find another way.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you had a look at attachments in org-mode http://orgmode.org/manual/Attachments.html?

Comment: @Dieter.Wilhelm I hestated to answer your suggestion, however, thank you very much. Ormode stores attachments in its own way. The manual says: »_Org uses directories named by the unique ID of each
entry.  These directories are located in the ‘data’ directory which
lives in the same directory where your Org file lives(1)._« This isn't possible for organisational reasons in my case.

Comment: No problem, you're welcome!